# mv if different, rm if same

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a tree of files and directories which I want to `mv path/to/src path/to/dest` on Linux.

This has already been attempted and as a result some (large) files have already been moved or copied, and some have been partially copied.

I want to complete the `mv`, but ignore any files which have already been copied, *and which are the same size as the source file*, and `rm` them instead.

i.e.

```
move_or_rm (src, dst):
    mkdir dst
    for each file f in src/*:
        if dst/f does not exist or dst/f is a different size from src/f:
            mv src/f dst/f
        else:
            rm src/f
    for each directory d in src/*:
        move_or_rm (src/d, dst/d)
```

(where f is a `path/to/some/file` relative to `src`)

I can knock this up in a script but is there a way to do it using standard Linux command line tools?

Comment: Have you considered `rsync` with the `--remove-source-files` option?

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside a script can be "zipped" into a single line, separing commands with `;`. However, in this case I would recommend using a script, as it involves some minimally complex logic.

To check if the file exist use the `-f` comparator. To check if two files are the same I'd use the `md5sum` command. Any different bit inside one of the files will throw a completely different md5 sum, so if they match, it means it's the same file. So:

```
if dst/f does not exist or dst/f is a different size from src/f:
```

Would be translated as:

```
if [ -f dst/f ] || [[ `md5sum src/f` != `md5sum dst/f` ]]; then
  cp src/f dst/f
fi
```

Comment: I wonder if `cmp` is faster or slower...

Answer (score 0):

I'll see if anyone posts a more succinct command-line-fu answer but here's what I have come up with in the meantime:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

COMMIT = False



def try_mv (src, dst):

    print ("mv {} {}".format (src, dst))

    if COMMIT:

        try:

            os.rename (src, dst)

        except Exception as e:

            print ("\t{}".format(e))

            return False

    return True



def try_rm (src):

    print ("rm " + src)

    if COMMIT:

        try:

            os.remove (src)

        except Exception as e:

            print ("\t{}".format(e))

            return False

    return True



def try_rmdir (src):

    print ("rmdir " + src)

    if COMMIT:

        try:

            os.rmdir (src)

        except Exception as e:

            print ("\t{}".format (e))

            return False

    return True



def mv_or_rm_if_exists (src_dir, dst_dir):

    if not os.path.isdir (src_dir):
        raise Exception (src_dir + " is not a directory.")

    if not os.path.isdir (dst_dir):

        if os.path.exists (dst_dir):
            raise Exception (dst_dir + " exists but is not a directory.")

        if COMMIT:
            os.mkdir (dst_dir)

    for name in os.listdir (src_dir):

        src_path = src_dir + "/" + name
        dst_path = dst_dir + "/" + name

        if os.path.isdir (src_path):

            mv_or_rm_if_exists (src_path, dst_path)

            try_rmdir (src_path)

        elif not os.path.isfile (src_path):

            print ("Skipping non-file " + src_path)

        elif not os.path.exists (dst_path):

            try_mv (src_path, dst_path)

        elif not os.path.isfile (dst_path):

            print ("Skipping {} because {} is not a file".format (src_path, dst_path))

        else:

            # src_path and dst_path both exist and are both files
            
            if os.path.getmtime (dst_path) > os.path.getmtime (src_path):
                print ("Skipping {} because its mtime is greater than that of {}".format (dst_path, src_path))
            elif os.path.getsize (src_path) == os.path.getsize (dst_path):
                try_rm (src_path)
            else:
                try_mv (src_path, dst_path)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    this_script = sys.argv.pop (0)

    # --commit may be first or last

    if sys.argv[0] == "--commit":
        COMMIT = True
        sys.argv.pop(0)

    if len (sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[2] == "--commit":
        COMMIT = True
        sys.argv.pop (2)

    if len (sys.argv) != 2:
        print ("Usage: {} (--commit) src dst".format (this_script))

    mv_or_rm_if_exists (sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1])
    try_rmdir (sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This function, which wraps just an `rsync` command, will do what you want.

```
move_or_rm()
{
    local src="$1" dst="$2"
    rsync -rvH --remove-source-files "$src/ "$dst"
}
```

It would be more reliable to include the date/time of the files too, in which case you'd replace `-rvH` with `-rtvH`.

To test it, you can add the `--dry-run` option to `rsync`, which will attempt to show you what it wants to do without actually doing it.